# Automatically create a report based on an R script and a template with Knitr

Tags: r, sweave, knitr

I'm using `stitch` function in Knitr 0.4. It works fine and gives the R script with  output in ##. I wonder how to make changes to only show the normal output with R code.

I tried to make the changes in `knitr-template.Rnw` but it did not work for me. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is unclear, but can probably be achieved by adding
the correct option to the `auto-report` chunk in the template.

If you want to add the `>` and `+` prompts back 
and remove the `##` prefix for the results, 
you can add `prompt=TRUE,comment=""`.

If you want to remove the code and only keep the output, 
you can use `echo=FALSE`.

If the output is already in LaTeX, you can use 
`results="tex"`.